# spamass-milter[1403]: Could not retrieve sendmail macro "i"!. Please add it to confMILTER_MACROS_ENVFROM for better spamassassin results

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, spamassassin, milter

I am running an Ubuntu 20.04 based LEMP server on a Raspberry Pi. Installed on it is postfix/dovecot/amavis/spamassassin. When I look at my mail.err logs by running the following command:

`cat /var/log/mail.err`
it returns the following errors:

```
spamass-milter[1606]: Could not retrieve sendmail macro "i"!.  Please add it to confMILTER_MACROS_ENVFROM for better spamassassin results
spamass-milter[1420]: Could not retrieve sendmail macro "i"!.  Please add it to confMILTER_MACROS_ENVFROM for better spamassassin results
spamass-milter[1595]: spamass-milter 0.4.0 starting
spamass-milter[1595]: Could not retrieve sendmail macro "i"!.  Please add it to confMILTER_MACROS_ENVFROM for better spamassassin results
```

What do these errors mean, and how I can fix them?

Answer (score 3):

Your milter expects a property of Sendmail which is not true for Postfix.

As documented in the [macro section of the postfix milter readme](https://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html#macros), the milter macro `i` provides the queue identifier, which is not immediately assigned (see `smtpd_delay_open_until_valid_rcpt` configuration) and hence not available to your spamass-milter program until later steps in the SMTP exchange.

Other than for verbose logging purposes there is no need whatsoever for a spam filtering milter to know the (arbitrarily assigned) QUEUE ID, so if it does not complicate your monitoring, you can safely disregard this warning.

---

As per [Debian Bug #696856](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=696856) Debian (and possibly derivatives) now ship a [patch](https://sources.debian.org/patches/spamass-milter/0.4.0-2/queueid_in_envrcpt/) that removes the too-early access and accompanying warning in spamass-milter.

Comment: How exactlydo I apply this patch @anx?

Comment: @DanRan That patch *is* applied in the `version >= 0.4.0-2` binaries built by Debian (and many derived distributions). If you are not using Debian packages, the precise methods for applying it depend on how you build your packages, but I am fairly certain that *unified diff* format can be used in each and every packaging toolkit.